# Give color customization ability to users

Tags: reactjs

I'm building an app-building tool and giving users the ability to customize their app appearance.

So based on user selection, I am immediately giving a preview of appearance besides color settings. I'm using CSS cascading and properties that users can't customize, I'm passing it via className= so and so and properties that can be customized, I'm doing that via in-line style.

It's not working.

Border value passed via in-style is not working as I can't see style element in the console.log at the respective div.

Also, I am not sure whether this is the right approach(I'm new to programming). Could someone help me fix this?

```
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState({
        borderColor: "",
        borderThinkness: "",
        background: "",
        fontColor:""
    }

    const handleColorChange =({ currentTarget: input })=>{
        const data = inputValue
        data[input.name] = input.value;
        setInputValue(data);
     }

const styleborder={
    border: ` ${inputValue.borderThinkness } solid ${inputValue.borderColor}`
}


    return (
        <div className="previewSide">
            <div style={styleborder} className="box boxextend">
       <div>
    

     <div className="configurationSide">
     <input onChange={handleColorChange} type="color" id="borderColor" name="borderColor"></input>
</div>
```

Comment: Try changing the border CSS to style, width, color. e.g. { border: `solid ${inputValue.borderThickness} {inputValue.borderColor}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i recommend is CSS variable

```
    const style = {
        "--primary-color": state.mainColor,
        "--primary-color-light": state.lightColor,
        "--primary-color-dark": state.darkColor,
        "--primary-color-on": "#fff",
    } as React.CSSProperties;
```

And insert this into your layout div's inline style and

Then you can handle it in  css.

```css
    .something {
            color: var(--primary-color);
        }
```

I've always done color customization like this.

Comment: This solution worked. But it's only picking only one Custom CSS variable at a time.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71410264/react-project-only-taking-one-custom-css-variable

Comment: @Newbie_developer
Well It is depended on how you write code, You can change all the css variables  with one setState. Am i understand correctly? if it is may i show you some example code?

Comment: Your answer is perfect. I fixed it using your ideas. Thanks a ton for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
setInputValue(data);
```

Do this:

> if you want to merge with previous data

```
setInputValue((prev) => ({ ...prev, ...data }));
```

> if you want to set new data

```
setInputValue(() => ({ ...data }));
```